# Fill in gaps between rooms in floor plan using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, fill

I am currently compiling a GIS of floors of a building. However, the current shapefiles have gaps between the rooms (the thickness of the walls-- shown below). I want to do some analysis on these rooms that require them to share boundaries.

How can I do this using ArcGIS Desktop?

I also use ArcPy and R.

[image]

EDIT

To follow up - yes I do need to know which rooms they share boundaries (Walls) with/are adjacent to. I also did a quick (rough) sketch of just a few of the areas that need to be sharing boundaries. Ideally- all of these rooms would be sharing walls at certain points with others. The dark green indicates areas that would most definitely be sharing a common boundary while the red indicates areas where there are furnaces, water heaters, etc. and don't need to be sharing common boundaries. 
[image]

Comment: You would almost need some application of the Minimum Bounding Geometry tool in ArcMap (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000) that would draw the outermost boundary of the rooms.

Comment: Do you need to know which rooms are adjacent to other rooms? Or share a common wall?

Comment: Can you mark on your picture examples where you would assess some "to share boundaries" and others not "to share boundaries"?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a polygon to cover the entire extent of the building.
2. Use the erase tool to erase the rooms from the extent polygon.
3. Convert the output polygon feature class to lines.
4. Explode to multipart.
5. Delete the outer boundary line (boundary of your extent polygon).
6. Delete any sections of walls that are on the outside:

[image]

7. You now have your walls:

[image]

8. Use the tool 'Collapse Dual Lines to Centerline'.

I don't have an advanced license so I cannot show the output of this tool.
You may need to resolve errors at the intersections.  Depending on the results of the tool, you may also need to split the walls at each corner so you have sets of corridors rather than one large and connected corridor.
The documentation explains the tool usage and output:

[Collapse Dual Lines to Centerline](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/collapse-dual-lines-to-centerline.htm#L_)